# Python-Django timezone is not working properly

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, pytz

I am working on Django based website. I am trying to get correct timezone and time to be displayed. But it is not working properly. I live in Dallas, Texas. So my default timezone is 'America/Chicago'.

My settings.py file has these lines of code.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I have datetime, and pytz installed. So when I am trying to save time in database, my codes are,

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

utc = pytz.utc

database = Database.objects.get(id=1)

databas.time = utc.localize(datetime.now())

database.save()
```

so when I check into database, updated time is `2015-10-20 23:13:04`

instead of `2015-10-20 18:13:04`

and when I print it out in template by codes below, I get this output `Oct. 20, 2015, 1:13 p.m.`

```
{{ database.time|localtime }}
```

I am confused how to use datetime, pytz and all to get accurate time along with settings.py file.

What I want to do is I want to save UTC time. But when I print out I want to get visitor's timezone and print time according to user. My website will be accessible only in United States for now. My model has

```
time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and it is saving some different time. I have another model where I have column named expire time where I am using following codes to save,

```
expire_time = utc.localize(datetime.now()+ timedelta(hours=24))
```

means I want to expire a link after 24 hours. But this timezone is confusing me. Can anyone help me? I don't know what should I use in my codes to get proper timezone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you set `USE_TZ = True` Django stores datetimes in UTC. Use the following to create a timezone aware `datetime.now`:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

database.time = timezone.now()
expire_time = timezone.now() + timedelta(hours=24)
```

You can then use [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate) to set the current time zone to the end user’s actual time zone.
Have a look at ["Selecting the current time zone"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) to see an example how a user can select his timezone and how this selection is used to activate his timezone.

Comment: So what should my settings.py codes? Are they correct? And as I said, `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` is not saving UTC time. I don't know why.

Comment: Yes, your settings are looking good. Can you please post the value of your "time" field after creating a new instance?

Comment: There is no code for time right now. I am not saving default time. I am updating expire time.

Comment: I thought the field `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` is called `time`. Anyway, can you post the value of a new instance with such a field. You wrote that this was "saving some different time."

Comment: I have updated my codes and now it is working as you have suggested in your answer. Thanx @Reto

Comment: @DjangoLearner glad I could help